# Sitecore 9.1 and auth0 integration

Tags: federated-authentication, identity-server, owin

I am trying to integrate Sitecore 9.1 and `auth0` platform. I was following this tutorial for Sitecore 9.0 - https://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/.

I managed to get `auth0` login screen but I am getting this error message after login:

> Error: An error occured.

[image]

I checked `Owin.log` file but it is empty, and I checked my `auth0` account and it says that I successfully logged in but I am still getting the same error.

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: Dionis, did you find out what was going on? We are facing a similar issue. Everything was working fine until one fine day, logging in CM give the error you are experiencing

Comment: I too am facing this issue with an upgraded site running 9.2. Any insights?

Comment: Facing the same issue, seemingly narrowed it down to where auth0 is returning a userid of zero. It's a client managed auth0 so I'm not sure if that's relevant for others facing this issue.